# Стоит ли использовать JSONB для хранения данных, по которым предстоит фильтроваться?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, jsonb

Есть задача сделать набор динамических атрибутов у объекта в БД. Они могут быть разных типов, например, числа и строки. Выбираю между тем, чтобы записывать их в JSONB поле в виде ключей и значений или сделать классическую таблицу с атрибутами one to many relation. Сильно ли скорость выборок по JSON будет ниже? Фильтрации будут простые, но объектов может быть довольно много. Или лучше использовать JSONB только для тех данных, по которым фильтрации не будет?

Comment: А "простые" фильтрации - это какие ? Скорость будет выше там где применяется индекс, как бы вы ни хранили. А вот применим ли индекс в вашем случае надо изучать. например gin индекс для jsonb позволяет искать только на точное равенство https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/datatype-json#json-indexing

Comment: @Mike Простые фильтрации на примере чисел - это например выбрать все значения у которых есть в jsonb такой-то ключ и значение в нем не больше стольки-то. Вот такого уровня фильтрации.

Comment: ну раз "не больше", значит это уже не точное равенство, значит применение индекса невозможно, со всеми вытекающими. А значит для поиска нужен EAV (отдельная таблица атрибутов) (хотя есть другие форматы хранения вида ключ-значение с другими индексами как доп. расширения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну с того, что лучше всё же проектировать
нормализованную схему по умолчанию. Из личного опыта
<del>мучений</del> работы с изменяемым *JSON(B)*
в *PostgreSQL* (правда, **до** включения в него
расширений *SQL/JSON*) я выработал простое эмпирическое
правило. Используйте *JSON(B)*, если:

1. данные либо неизменяемые, либо заменяемые
   целиком, и…
2. данные небольшие (≤ 2–3 КиБ), и…
3. у вас **действительно** будут разные запросы
   по разным частям этих данных.

Если вы собираетесь эти атрибуты менять, то я бы всё же
рекомендовал нормализованные данные. Насчёт же скорости работы
судить без реальных данных тяжело, да и от машины может
зависеть. Но на небольших данных, средней машине,
и с подходящими индексами замедление *JSON(B)* критичным быть
не должно.